# Download GeoTiff from geoserver in World Wind

Tags: java, geoserver, wms, worldwind

I am trying to download a tiff file using a wms request to a geoserver so that I can run it through a geotiff parser in World Wind. Using the World Wind Java SDK I can parse a tiff file that is stored locally on the computer but I need to be able to parse one that is on a geoserver. Any idea how I can do this? Because the tools are already there to parse it locally, I figured maybe I can just write code to download the server request locally and pass it in so that I don't have to rewrite the parser. World Wind has support for parsing WMS requests but I need to be able to parse a wms request that returns a tiff file.

Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not a very good programmer; this might not be a good solution but it should work.

In the "ImportImagery.java" example here:

http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/dataimport/

I edited the ImportImagery() method to include three inputs String filepath String extension and AppFrame appframe.  Inside this method is "ExampleUtil.saveResourcetoTempFile(filepath, extension).  This is what reads the imagery.  Although I am inputting a filepath, a URL can be  accepted too.

http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/daily/docs/api/index.html